# OpenMP (C++): Matrix multiplication with dynamically created arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, openmp, matrix-multiplication

I just started working with OpenMP and I have found it really handy when it comes to speeding up a program. I am trying to speed-up the multiplication of two, 2d matrices (arrays). I actually did it successfully with static arrays like this:

```
omp_set_num_threads(8);
#pragma omp parallel default(shared)
{
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:C[:N])
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j <P; ++j){
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < M; ++k){
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I am facing some difficulties when I am initializing the "C" array dynamically like this:

```
double **C = new double*[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    C[i] = new double[P];
}
```

The error the G++ compiler is throwing is this:

```
error: user defined reduction not found for ‘*C’
```

Okey, it looks like I can not use the specific way for dynamic arrays, how should I use OpenMP for dynamically created arrays?

EDIT: THANKS TO

> @Alain Merigot

FOR POINTING OUT THAT REDUCTION IS NOT NEEDED

The execution time is much higher on dynamically created array with multi-thread than without it which still means that the code for static can not be used for the dynamic ones

Comment: How is `C` defined in your first working example?  What does your multiplication loop look like for the second nonworking example?

Comment: `C` is defined like this `double C[N][P];` The multiplication is the exact same I just changed the way of initializing the 2d array `C`

Comment: You do *not* need a reduction. Reduction are useful to accumulate on a variable shared by different threads. But you parallelize on the `i` loop and all C[i][j] will be different. All the accumulations on a given C[i][j] will be performed by the same thread and reductions are useless.

Comment: @AlainMerigot You are right I just edited the question  a bit

Comment: To clarify why your execution time is much longer, `C[100][100]` will not actually become an array of pointers to arrays, so your memory will not be all over the place. Instead, it will become a 1D array storing a matrix in row major format. If you want to speed up matrix multiplication, first start storing matrices in 1D arrays, you are using C++ so you may even consider a nice class for this, that way you can maintain the ease of use (i.e. add `double& operator () (size_t x, size_t y)`) to your class. For even faster matrix multiplication though, consider looking at BLAS.

Comment: Also, it is possible to define your own reduction in OpenMP. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to write up a proper answer with all the relevant example code right now.

Comment: Backing up @qbit... Look at BLAS Libraries. Matrix multiplication is more complicated than you would reasonably expect (vectorization, blocking, ...). Since "The best code is the code I don't have to write", get a free BLAS (like Intel MKL https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl which is free for anyone). (I know, it;s more fun to write code than read a manual, but why beat your head against a problem which already has good, free, solutions?)

Comment: @JimCownie it is just a way to train my mind this is why I am not using BLAS Libraries

Comment: @KarampistisDimitrios which is fine, as long as at the end of it you don;t think you learned all of the ways to optimize matrix multiplication, so when you have to use that operation in real life, yo use a BLAS library, rather than our own code.